# Why is Little Ronnie's place not available on the internet if he is so famous?

Tags: downsizing-2017

In Sci-fi Downsizing (2017), Paul and Dusan are discussing Little Ronni's place, which is in Norway:

> Dusan: **Konrad, too.** We make business there. Very good business.
>
> Paul: Must be something to see. You know you can't even get pictures
>   of it online?
>
> Dusan: Yes, my friend. The world is filled with things to see.

Actual Little Ronni is a first small baby ever born. So Why is Little Ronnie's place not available on the internet if he is so famous?

Comment: Isn't the base in Norway some kind of commune filled with hippies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little Ronnie lives in a commune (which see later in the film) situated on private land. The only way to access it is by boat and the only people who're allowed to go there appear to be honoured guests and favoured suppliers which drastically limits the number of visitors.

At the end of the film we learn that not only is this commune an experiment in sustainable living, but also an eco-doomsday cult. The people leading the colony are convinced that humanity is on the verge of extinction and arrange for a secret hide-away to be built in the vicinity of the colony in which they can wait out the apocalypse.

Since mobile phones with cameras don't appear to be a ubiquitous technology among the miniaturised and given the secrecy in which the colony lives, there's a very limited scope for people to be taking photos and publishing those on the Internet.